# LINQ parsing - How do I target the child?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<options>
    <!-- Set the start page of the module -->
    <startpage>google.com</startpage>

    <alloweddomains>
        <domain>mail.google.com</domain>
        <domain>calendar.google.com</domain>
    </alloweddomains>
</options>
```

And my code looks lime this:

```
 var xdoc = XDocument.Load("Options/Options.xml");
 var allowedDomains = xdoc.Descendants("alloweddomains")
                          .Attributes("domain");

 foreach (var xAttribute in allowedDomains)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Allowed domains: " + xAttribute.Name); 
 }
```

It keeps saying my allowedDomain is null thought (not the xdoc). Am I targetting the domain wrongly?  If so, how do I target the domain.

Thanks everyone for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have an attributes on your `alloweddomains` element named `domain`, you have *elements*

```
xdoc.Descendants("alloweddomains").Elements("domain");
```

Alternatively, assuming you don't have `domain` elements anywhere else you can simply do

```
xdoc.Descendants("domain")
```

Comment: I f*cking hate XML! Youre absolutely correct. Will mark it as such in 10 minutes.

Comment: Wise words, @James. Thank you for the perspective :)